# Water : Aquatic :: Sand : xxx?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, etymology, adjectives, analogy

Just as *aquatic* is to *water* and *aerial* is to *air*, what is an equivalent word for *sand* (or *earth*, I suppose)?

For context, I’m trying to describe the locomotion of worms *within* desert sand (as opposed to its *surface*). Ergo, *terrestrial* isn’t particularly suitable and neither is *earthy*.

Comment: Studying arenicolites?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, fancy words for ‘sandy’ are *arenarious* and *arenaceous*, with the second apparently preferred.   Perhaps one of those two will do.

You can also use *arenaceo-* as a combining form.  Darwin did, when he wrote of *arenaceo-calcareous loam*.

---

### Edit

Oh wait, there is one for just what you want here.  From the *OED*:

> **arenicolous** /-ələs/, a.
>
> Etymology: f. as prec. + -ous.
>
> Inhabiting sand.
>
> - 1851-9 Owen in *Man. Sc. Enq*. 381 ― Arenicolous mollusks.

The preceding entry referenced above is:

> **arenicolite** /ærɪˈnɪkəlaɪt/.
>
> Etymology: f. mod.L. *arēnicol-a* sand-worm, lob-worm (f. *arēna* sand + *‑cola* inhabiting) + *‑ite*.
>
> A worm-hole made originally in sand, and preserved in a sandstone rock.
>
> 1864 in Webster.

Once you remember that [Latin had *arena*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arena#Latin) for sand (as do Spanish, Italian, Catalan, Portuguese, and various others), the rest is easy: just look for words that start with *arena-* or *areni-*, of which we have a fair number.  As another example, *arenosity* is sandiness.

I also looked for things related to [Latin *sabulum*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sabulum) for gravel, [modern French *sable*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sable#French) for sand, but it was not productive, as [all our English uses of *sable*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sable#English) are related to the furry critter, to black,  or to heraldry.   We have no *sabl-* words related to sand.

Comment: Muchas gracias. That is simply perfect. Fancy words++